# Ajax not working on Server

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have downloaded the latest toolkit from https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/.
Problem is it works fine on my local host but not when i upload it to the server. I don't even get an error message. Simply anything Ajax related is not working. I'm suspecting that the installation I did is the problem, since it does everything automatically for me and in my project I can't add a **ScriptManager** since it keeps saying that I already have one in my system, eventhough I can't see in anywhere in my code.
Do anyone have any idea what the problem might be or what I'm missing?

Comment: Is your script manager on the master page?

Comment: haha yes it was, it was already bulit in my project. I just deleted it and put in my default page and now its working thanks alot man! 
Just add your answer and i will give you a correct answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a ScriptManager on the master page, and therefore when your child page gets composited with the master page there ends up being two script managers.

The normal solution is to only have the ScriptManager on the master page.